# Are there problems with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 in Android 2.1?

Tags: android, testing, functional-testing

After I have set up all the unit test cases for my android application I now also want to do functional testing. But I encouter one problem. As I am developping for the HTC Legend I can, by now, only use android platforms up to 2.1. But in some way it seems that the **ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2** won't work.

```
public SupplierSelectoinTest() {
    super("com.sap.catalogue.activities", SupplierSelection.class);
}
```

This simple piece of code gives me the following error, when I try to run the test:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.sap.catalogue.activities/com.sap.catalogue.activities.SupplierSelection }
at android.app.Instrumentation.startActivitySync(Instrumentation.java:371)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivityWithIntent(InstrumentationTestCase.java:120)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivity(InstrumentationTestCase.java:98)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.getActivity(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:87)
at com.sap.catalogue.test.acceptance.SupplierSelectoinTest.setUp(SupplierSelectoinTest.java:27)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:430)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
```

I read through all tutorials and all I get out of it is, that it should work but it doesn't. Anyway, when I switch to android 2.2 (which is no solution for now) and I use the new constructor, where I only need to hand in the activity class and not the pkg string the emulator will run the tests without complaining.

But there has to be a way to get this running in android 2.1!

**In addition**
These are my two Manifest.xml files. The first one, is the one of the application itself. The other one is the one of the test project.

**Application Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.sap.catalogue"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Catalogue"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity android:name=".activities.CategoryBrowser"></activity>

<activity android:name=".activities.ProductDetails"></activity>
<activity android:name=".activities.ProductSearch"></activity>
<activity android:name=".activities.ProductView"></activity>
<activity android:name=".activities.SupplierSelection"></activity>

</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

**Test Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.sap.catalogue.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <instrumentation android:targetPackage="com.sap.catalogue" android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the top level package name.

```
public SupplierSelectoinTest() {
    super("com.sap.catalogue", SupplierSelection.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you didn't write the activity in the Manifest.xml. Would you share it also?

Edit:

Add this to the test Manifest.xml. I think, this will solve your problem.

```
<activity android:name="com.sap.catalogue.activities.SupplierSelection"></activity>
```

Comment: Which one do you mean? The Manifest.xml of the test project or of the application itself?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Even with this line in the Manifest.xml it gives me exactly the same error.