# ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 throwing java.lang.RuntimeException for unable to resolve Activity

Tags: android, unit-testing, tdd, android-testing

This problem popped up recently on one of my development machines. I haven't yet verified it on my other machine, but yesterday I was not having this problem on that machine.

The problem I'm having is when I'm running my tests for my ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 inherited classes. My device is not in lock-screen. I'm getting the following Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.xilconic.achieveitall/.util.activities.TestingFragmentActivity }
at android.app.Instrumentation.startActivitySync(Instrumentation.java:379)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivityWithIntent(InstrumentationTestCase.java:119)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.launchActivity(InstrumentationTestCase.java:97)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.getActivity(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:104)
at com.xilconic.achieveitall.test.fragments.goalsoverview.GoalsOverviewFragmentTests.setUp(GoalsOverviewFragmentTests.java:24)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

My code:

**Testing class:**

public class GoalsOverviewFragmentTests extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    private TestingFragmentActivity activity;

```
public GoalsOverviewFragmentTests(){
    super(TestingFragmentActivity.class);
}

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception{
    super.setUp();
    activity = getActivity();
}

    // Testing methods here

}
```

**Android Manifest (regular project):**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xilconic.achieveitall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.xilconic.achieveitall.GoalTargetsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.xilconic.achieveitall.util.activities.TestingFragmentActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Android Manifest (Test project):**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xilconic.achieveitall.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.xilconic.achieveitall" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I've already tried the suggestion presented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957663/are-there-problems-with-activityinstrumentationtestcase2-in-android-2-1, where adding the top-level package of my regular project did not solve my problem. I kept having the same Exception (also is an deprecated constructor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Delete the bin and gen folder, then refreshing the eclipse project.

The problem I was having, was that the contents of my bin and gen folder had gotten out of sync.

**Note:**

Another symptom that you are having this problem, is that you are having problems or warnings that make not sense.

In my particular case, I was having a strange warning that I fixed on my other machine and comitted it, but then ended up seeing it again on this particular machine even though the problem was no longer to be found in my code.